# Start Activity after orientation changed to landscape

Tags: android

If im on a Smartphone and when i rotate the screen to landscape i need to start an `Activity`. For now i do this in the `onResume()` of my `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (!HelperDevice.isTablet(this.getContext())) {
        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            this.getActivity().startActivityForResult(new Intent(this.getActivity(), ActivityImageInspirations.class), Globals.REQUEST_IMAGE_INSPIRATIONS);
        }
    }
}
```

This is working perfectly on `Nexus 4` but on `Nexus 5` for example the screen is flickering like 10 or more times until it starts the activity successfully. it seems like the activity is started and finished instantly what causes the flickering.

What could cause such an behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `Override` the function `onOrientationChange` instead of `onResume`

Comment: but there is no `onOrientationChange` in a fragment

Comment: Is it necessary to handle the change in Fragment? Can't you do it in the Activity?

Comment: You've an activity from which you're replacing the `Fragment` right? Start your `startActivityForResult` from the parent `Activity` then.